# How to center spatial data

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am mapping spacial data (Lat/Long) to data points around the country (Australia). I find that the map area changes every time I run my query. e.g. If there are no results in Western Australia, Western Australia will disappear off the map, and the rest of the country will be zoomed in on.

I can not for the life of my figure out to anchor the map tilelayer to show the entire country every single time, and not move according to where the data points returned are.

Comment: I've never done anything with this type of data but my instinct would be to add two locations that would be at the top left and bottom right of an imaginary rectangle drawn around your desired map area. As these would always be displayed, and always be the most extreme points, the map would center as you expected.

Comment: Thank you. managed to get through it with this solution.

Comment: I'll add the comment as an answer so you can mark it as answered.This will help others when searching for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done anything with this type of data but my instinct would be to add two locations that would be at the top left and bottom right of an imaginary rectangle drawn around your desired map area. As these would always be displayed, and always be the most extreme points, the map would center as you expected.